# Integrating solr and openNLP

Tags: solr, lucene

I followed this link to integrate https://wiki.apache.org/solr/OpenNLP

> Installation
>
> For English language testing: Until LUCENE-2899 is committed:
>
> 1. pull the latest trunk or 4.0 branch
> 2. apply the latest LUCENE-2899 patch
> 3. do 'ant compile'
> 4. cd solr/contrib/opennlp/src/test-files/training

I followed first two steps but got the following error while executing 3rd point

```
common.compile-core:
[javac] Compiling 10 source files to /home/biginfolabs/solrtest/solr-lucene-trunk3/lucene/build/analysis/opennlp/classes/java

[javac] warning: [path] bad path element "/home/biginfolabs/solrtest/solr-lucene-trunk3/lucene/analysis/opennlp/lib/jwnl-1.3.3.jar": no such file or directory

[javac] /home/biginfolabs/solrtest/solr-lucene-trunk3/lucene/analysis/opennlp/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/opennlp/FilterPayloadsFilter.java:43: error: cannot find symbol

[javac]     super(Version.LUCENE_44, input);

[javac]                  ^
[javac]   symbol:   variable LUCENE_44
[javac]   location: class Version
[javac] /home/biginfolabs/solrtest/solr-lucene-trunk3/lucene/analysis/opennlp/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/opennlp/OpenNLPTokenizer.java:56: error: no suitable constructor found for Tokenizer(Reader)
[javac]     super(input);
[javac]     ^
[javac]     constructor Tokenizer.Tokenizer(AttributeFactory) is not applicable
[javac]       (actual argument Reader cannot be converted to AttributeFactory by method invocation conversion)
[javac]     constructor Tokenizer.Tokenizer() is not applicable
[javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
[javac] 2 errors
[javac] 1 warning
```

Im really stuck how to passthough this step. I wasted my entire to fix this but couldn't move a bit. Please someone help me..?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integrating solr with openNLP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990245/integrating-solr-with-opennlp)

Comment: @ mindas: yes, i created this because i couldn't put the error log properly

Comment: Then you should delete the old one.

Comment: What is the SVN URL you used to perform the first step *pull the latest trunk or 4.0 branch*? As the error message quotes there is source code that shall be compiled that targets `LUCENE_44`, not `LUCENE_40`.

Comment: @cheffe: svn checkout http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk solr-lucene-trunk(i guess its the latest trunk). If this link is not correct one, can you please provide the right link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the patch seems to be written against Lucence 4.0. You should also attempt to use the patch with Lucene 4.0 sources. These can be found over [the SVN tags of Lucene's repository](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/tags/)

The 4.0 sources will be found here http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/tags/lucene_solr_4_0_0/

Comment: @ cheffe: I pulled 4.0 only and i compiled. I got one error instead 2. And the error is repeating. Pasting it  [javac] /home/biginfolabs/solrtest/solr-lucene-trunk10/lucene/analysis/opennlp/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/opennlp/FilterPayloadsFilter.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     super(Version.LUCENE_44, input);
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable LUCENE_44
    [javac]   location: class Version
    [javac] 1 error
    [javac] 1 warning

Comment: @ cheffe: small correction use 4_4_0 instead. And I'm able to compile now. I even did all steps but im getting this error Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/tokenizer: Error loading class 'solr.OpenNLPTokenizerFactory. I know that im missing solr to point to jar which contains OpenNLPTokenizerFactory. But i don't know where the jar is??? Please help to find it????